# Can't REG ADD DWORD value of /d 15

Tags: windows-registry

I'm trying to add a DWORD value to the registry. However, when I open the entry the value data is *f* and not the numeric value of 15.

`REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\NVIDIA Corporation\Global\GridLicensing" /v LicenseInterval /t REG_DWORD /d 15`

If I manually set the regkey and then export it, the hex value is: 00000015

If I enter this into my REG ADD command the key still displays a value of 000000f or f if I open it up.

Any ideas why this doesn't seem to work when adding the value using reg add?

Comment: Can we assume you are merging a .reg file you made into the registry?

Answer (score 1):

The value `15` is taken as decimal, which in hexadecimal is `F`.

For entering a hex value, the `/d` flag requires that you preface the 8-character hex value with `0x`.

Write it like this: `/d 0x00000015`